# хочу удалить последний напечатанный символ и правильно найти интервал

Tags: python, python-3.x

В самом внизу сам код.

Хотел бы, чтобы не выводил последний `|` и правильное количество раз выводил `-`.
Вот примеры:

ввод:

```
2
10
```

вывод:

```
x|p|x|p|x|p|x|p|x
-----------------
p|x|p|p|x|p|p|x|p
-----------------
x|p|x|p|x|p|x| |x
-----------------
p|p|p|x|p|p|p|p|x
-----------------
x|x|x|p|x|p|x|x|x
-----------------
p|p|p|p|p|x|p|p|p
-----------------
x|p|x|p|x|p|x| |x
-----------------
p|x| |p|x|p| |x| 
-----------------
x|p|x|x|x|p|x| |x
```

Вот еще один пример -

ввод:

```
11
10
```

вывод:

```
x|p
---
p|x
```

Тут пример как работает мой код

ввод:

```
2
10
```

вывод:

```
x|p|x|p|x|p|x|p|x|
--------
p|x|p|p|x|p|p|x|p|
--------
x|p|x|p|x|p|x| |x|
--------
p|p|p|x|p|p|p|p|x|
--------
x|x|x|p|x|p|x|x|x|
--------
p|p|p|p|p|x|p|p|p|
--------
x|p|x|p|x|p|x| |x|
--------
p|x| |p|x|p| |x| |
--------
x|p|x|x|x|p|x| |x|
--------
```

пример второй

ввод:

```
11
10
```

вывод:

```
x|p|
-
p|x|
-
```

Вот сам код:

```
import math

a = int(input())
b = int(input())

if a<2 or b<2 or a==b:
    print('ERROR') 

def gcd(x,y):
    if y==0:
        return x
    else:
        return gcd(y, x%y)

def task(x,y):
    return gcd(x,y)==1

def isPrime(n):
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0 or n <= 1:
        return False
    sqr = int(math.sqrt(n)+1)

    for k in range(3, sqr, 2):
        if n % k == 0:
            return False
    return True


for i in range(a, b+1):
    for j in range(a, b+1):
        if task(i,j)==True and (isPrime(i) == True or isPrime(j) == True):
            print("p", end="")
        elif task(i,j)==False:
            print("x", end="")
        else:
            print(" ", end="")
        print("|" , end='')
    print("")
    for k in range(a, b):
        print("-", end="")
    print("") 

if a > b:
    for i in range(b, a+1):
        for j in range(b, a+1):
            if task(i,j)==True and (isPrime(i) == True or isPrime(j) == True):
                print("p", end="")
            elif task(i,j)==False:
                print("x", end="")
            else:
                print(" ", end="")
            print("|" ,end='') 

        print("")
        for k in range(b, a):
            print("-", end="")
        print("")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пара советов, но можно игнорировать:

- исполняемый код пишите в main функции и вызывайте через  `if __name__ == '__main__': main()`
- названия пишите функций в snake_case
- сравнивайте `True` или `False` через `is`, однако если вам нужна *правдивость*, то просто опустите сравнение, или укажите `not`

Собственно решение (немного подчистил, не обессудьте)

```py
from functools import lru_cache

import math


@lru_cache()
def gcd(x, y):
    return x if y == 0 else gcd(y, x % y)


@lru_cache()
def task(x, y):
    return gcd(x, y) == 1


@lru_cache()
def is_prime(n):
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0 or n <= 1:
        return False
    sqr = int(math.sqrt(n) + 1)

    for k in range(3, sqr, 2):
        if n % k == 0:
            return False
    return True


def print_table(x, y):
    line = '\n' + '--' * abs(y - x) + '-\n'
    print(line.join([
        '|'.join([
            'x' if not task(i, j) else 'p' if is_prime(i) or is_prime(j) else ' '
            for j in range(x, y + 1)
        ])
        for i in range(x, y + 1)
    ]))


def main():
    a = int(input())
    b = int(input())

    if a < 2 or b < 2 or a == b:
        print('ERROR')

    print_table(a, b)
    if a > b:
        print_table(b, a)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**ОБНОВЛЕНО:**

- Вместо for -> if -> append использовано [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- Добавлен декоратор [`@lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=lru_cache#functools.lru_cache) для ускорения работы

Comment: спасибо большое, ваш код намного понятнее, чем мой, буду придерживаться. Ряльн, так кайфово читать такой код

Comment: хотел бы только узнать, как можно ускорить код?

Comment: @Khimer , обновил, должно чутка выиграть в скорости при больших числах ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: чем больше выделите max_size в lru_cache при больших числах - тем быстрее будет работать, однако... памяти жрать будет конечно...

Comment: спасибо, понятно